# Common type restrictions in JSON schema

Tags: jsonschema

can I have common type restrictions or a new type, which I could use for more properties in JSON scema? I am referencing some type properties, but I do not get what I would like to. For instance:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "Common types",
    "definitions": {
        "YN": {
            "description": "Y or N field (can be empty, too)",
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 0,
            "maxLength": 1,
            "enum": [ "Y", "N", "" ]
        },
        "HHMM": {
            "description": "Time in HHMM format (or empty).",
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 0,
            "maxLength": 4,
            "pattern": "^[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9]$|^$"
        }
    },
    "properties" : {
        "is_registered": {
            "description": "User registered. (this description is overriden)",
            "$ref": "#/definitions/YN"
        },
        "is_valid": {
            "description": "User valid. (this description is overriden)",
            "$ref": "#/definitions/YN"
        },
        "timeofday": {
            "description": "User registered at HHMM. (this description is overriden)",
            "$ref": "#/definitions/HHMM"
        }
    }
}
```

In the presented schema I have two strings with some restrictions (enum, pattern, etc.). I do not want to repeat these restrictions in every field of such type. Therefore, I have defined them in definitions and reused them. If type constraints changes, I change only the definitions.

However, there are two issues I have.

First, `description` is duplicated. If I load this into XMLSpy, only the description of the type is shown and not the description of the actual field. If the description of the type is empty, description of field is not used. I tried combining `title`, and `description` in a way that title would be used from common definition and description would be used from field description. It seems that always title and description are used from the common type definition. How could I use common type and the description of the field, which tells, what this field actually is.

Second, if description is inherited from definitions, can I just use common `pattern` or any other type property, and reference the pattern defined somehow in definitions or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to answer your question, first consider that JSON Schema does not have inheritance, only references.

For draft-04, using references mean that the WHOLE subschema object is replaced by the referenced schema object. This means your more specific field description is lost. (You can wrap them in `allOf`'s but it probably won't do what you want in terms of generating documentation).

If you can move to draft 2019-09, `$ref` can be used alongside other keywords, as it is then classified as an applicator keyword. I don't know if the tooling your using will work as you expect though.

In terms of your second question, not built in to JSON Schema. `$ref` references can only be used when you have a schema (or subschema). If you want to de-duplicate common parts which are NOT schemas, a common approach is to use a templating engine and compile your schemas at build or runtime. I've seen this done at scale using jsonnet.